# txt file delete url to last "/" to get files

Tags: regex, linux, windows, bash, notepad++

I have txt file contaning one url per row each url as:

```
://url/files.php?file=parent/children/file.pdf
://url/files.php?file=parent/children2/childrenofchildren2/file2.txt
......etc
```

I need help to cut everythink before last `/` in a row. That is what I used in notepad++ regex mode (it doesnt work):

```
^.+[/](.*)$
```

To get:

```
file.pdf
file2.txt
```

But I am open to all waysof solving.

Comment: In NPP, you can use `^.*/` to replace with `/` (if you need to keep the last `/`).

Comment: Nope `^.*/` ignores end of line I tried this before it will select everything except last line ending.

Comment: Is this really your problem @Aroly7? You've got this tagged as `windows`, `linux` and `bash`, so maybe you're trying to do this in a terminal? Or were those tags just for fun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line from left including `/` by nothing:

```
sed 's/.*\///' file
```

or

```
sed 's|.*/||' file
```

Output:

```
file.pdf
file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrus, my Windows part of mind overpowered my Linux part so I don't think about this way. Huge thanks

Comment: or use `/` as field separator and output last column with `awk`: `awk -F / '{print $NF}' file`

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be more complicated than it needs to be, but it works!

A purely regex-based approach could be as follows:
`(([^\/])*)((\n)|($))/g`

Basically, it matches any number of non-newline and non `\` characters  `(([^\/])*)` and then stops when it either encounters a new line `\n`or the end of the sequence `$`. The global `/g` is also set, to allow it to match more than one instance!

I hope this helped!